# как в FLutter обработь параметры из ответа от Get-запроса?

Tags: json, get, flutter

У меня есть функция, где я запрашиваю с сервера изображение для пользователя.

```
_GetEnrolmentImageForUser({required String nUserId}) async {
  final url = Uri.parse(
      "http://10.0.2.2:123/api/DB/GetImageForUser/" + nUserId);
  final client = HttpClient();
  final request = await client.postUrl(url);

  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
}
```

На текущий момент я получаю респонс корректно. Выглядит json так:

```
{ "sUserImage": "огромная строка", "sErrorMessage": null }
```

но я не понимаю, как мне в рамках этой функции обработать джейсон чтобы забрать sUserImage.

Единственное что мне пришло в голову, это сделать так, но я уверен, что оно не будет работать (к сожалению, до завтра нет возможности проверить):

```
String _sUserImage = json.decode(response.body).[sUserImage];
```

А как будет правильно?

В сети сходу нашёл только [такой вариант](https://habr.com/ru/articles/560964/)  и [такой вариант](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) решения, но считаю его не очень подходящим для моего случая (слишком много кода ради получения одной строки).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам вопрос задал, сам ответ нашёл:
Сначлаа декодируем json, а затем можем получать доступ к элементам:

```
final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
sUserImage = jsonData['sUserImage'];
```